# R - Extract values depending on multiple conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, extract

I have 2 dataframes, here are the codes:

```
set.seed(100)

x1= rnorm(4)
x2= rnorm(4)
x3= rnorm(4)
x4= rnorm(4)
x5= rnorm(4)
x6= rnorm(4)
x7= rnorm(4)
x8= rnorm(4)
x9= rnorm(4)
x10= rnorm(4)
df1 = data.frame(Station1 = x1, Station2 = x2, Station3 = x3, Station4 = x4, Station5 = x5, Station6 = x6, Station7 = x7, Station8 = x8, Station9 = x9, Station10 = x10) 

x1= c("Station1", "Station2", "Station3", "Station4", "Station5", "Station6", "Station7", "Station8", "Station9", "Station10")
x2= seq(-2,10 , length=10)
x3= seq(30, 45, length=10)
x4= c(1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 1)
x5= seq(4, 16, length=10)
df2 = data.frame(Station=x1, Lon=x2, Lat=x3, Number=x4, Mis=x5)
```

Now I want to extract certain values of df1 and add them in a new column in df2. The df2$Number column goes from 1-4, just like the number of rows in df1. When there is a 1 in the df2$Number of Station1 I want to extract the value of the 1st row of df1 of the matching Station1. Another example would be: df2$Number for Station2 is 3, so I want to extract the value in the 3rd row of Station2 in df1, that would be -0.5817907.

All of these extracted values should be added in a new column in df2.

Here my examples:

```
>df1
    Station1   Station2    Station3    Station4   Station5   Station6   Station7    Station8   Station9  Station10
1 -0.50219235  0.1169713 -0.82525943 -0.20163395 -0.3888542 -0.4380900 -0.8143791 -1.15772946 -0.1379296
2  0.13153117  0.3186301 -0.35986213  0.73984050  0.5108563  0.7640606 -0.4384506  0.24707599 -0.1111935
3 -0.07891709 -0.5817907  0.08988614  0.12337950 -0.9138142  0.2619613 -0.7202216 -0.09111356 -0.6900143
4  0.88678481  0.7145327  0.09627446 -0.02931671  2.3102968  0.7734046  0.2309445  1.75737562 -0.2217942 0.1829077 0.4173233 1.0654023 0.9702020

> df2
    Station        Lon      Lat Number       Mis
1   Station1 -2.0000000 30.00000      1  4.000000
2   Station2 -0.6666667 31.66667      3  5.333333
3   Station3  0.6666667 33.33333      2  6.666667
4   Station4  2.0000000 35.00000      1  8.000000
5   Station5  3.3333333 36.66667      4  9.333333
6   Station6  4.6666667 38.33333      2 10.666667
7   Station7  6.0000000 40.00000      4 12.000000
8   Station8  7.3333333 41.66667      3 13.333333
9   Station9  8.6666667 43.33333      3 14.666667
10 Station10 10.0000000 45.00000      1 16.000000
```

Here are Links to my actual dataframes:

df1: https://megastore.uni-augsburg.de/get/IftpNjXNqL/

df2: https://megastore.uni-augsburg.de/get/8_Y6SPVCA9/

Comment: And just a question: Why do I get downvotes for my question right away? What is wrong with it? I am really trying to make it as clear as possible, provide all information and spend a lot of time in writing it.

Comment: I think you should add a column `Number` to df1 and then `melt` df1 to 1 obs per `Number` per `Station`.  Then do `df2` left join `df1` on `Station` and `Number`.

Comment: You asked what to do differently in the future.  I thought your question was fine.  But consider defining the dataset statically instead of randomly (with something like `dput()`, `data.frame()`, or `tibble::tribble()`).  Also, consider specifying the desired output or vector (like `value` in my answer, and `New` in @erocoar's).  I assume you've seen this, or something like it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.

Comment: Thank, I try to change these things!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df2$Station <- as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]", "", df2$Station))
df2$New <- apply(df2, 1, function(x) df1[x[4], x[1]])

df2

   Station        Lon      Lat Number       Mis         New
1        1 -2.0000000 30.00000      1  4.000000 -0.50219235
2        2 -0.6666667 31.66667      3  5.333333 -0.58179068
3        3  0.6666667 33.33333      2  6.666667 -0.35986213
4        4  2.0000000 35.00000      1  8.000000 -0.20163395
5        5  3.3333333 36.66667      4  9.333333  2.31029682
6        6  4.6666667 38.33333      2 10.666667  0.76406062
7        7  6.0000000 40.00000      4 12.000000  0.23094453
8        8  7.3333333 41.66667      3 13.333333 -0.09111356
9        9  8.6666667 43.33333      3 14.666667 -0.69001432
10      10 10.0000000 45.00000      1 16.000000  0.18290768
```

This would be one option - just change the Station column to numeric for indexing and get the values by looping through it with apply

Edit: For your real data, the column indexes are different and regex may or may not work - so I would do it this way:

```
MainFrame$New <- apply(MainFrame, 1, function(x) Centroids[x[3], x[1]])
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats already a big step for me. I only need to save the real Stationnames. But that I can manage by myself! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, you could also just store the index created in a variable other than Station. Glad it helped :)

Comment: Hi, I have big problems adapting the code to my real dataframe. I dont know whats the problem, but I get error massages all the time. It works so fine for my testframe. Could you please have a look on my real dataframes? I uploaded them and the link is above!

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked perfectly! The strange thing is that I tried that yesterday, 1:1 in the same way, but it didnt work. I changed the Stations to numerics, and it doesnt work then.

Answer (score 2):

A conventional database approach would convert `df1` to a long/tall dataset.  Then the selection is performed with a left join (with a package like [dplyr](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html), [data.table](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.8.0/topics/data.table), or even [`base::merge()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html)).

```
library(magrittr)
df_value_long <- df1 %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    Number   = seq_len(n())
  ) %>% 
  tidyr::gather(Station, value, -Number)

df2b <- df2 %>% 
  dplyr::left_join(df_value_long, by=c("Station", "Number"))
```

*df_value_long*:

```
   Number   Station       value
1       1  Station1 -0.50219235
2       2  Station1  0.13153117
3       3  Station1 -0.07891709
4       4  Station1  0.88678481
5       1  Station2  0.11697127
6       2  Station2  0.31863009
7       3  Station2 -0.58179068
8       4  Station2  0.71453271
...
```

*df2b*:

```
     Station        Lon      Lat Number       Mis       value
1   Station1 -2.0000000 30.00000      1  4.000000 -0.50219235
2   Station2 -0.6666667 31.66667      3  5.333333 -0.58179068
3   Station3  0.6666667 33.33333      2  6.666667 -0.35986213
...
```

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure about converting. My real dataframe is huge it might take a lot of time. But on the other hand I dont have to overwrite my stations with this solution. I will look what is better for me.

Comment: Large datasets typically come from databases, and databases are usually designed to be tall.  But if your original source is already wide, I see the advantage of @erocoar's approach.  I added this to his approach mostly for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really love to have different solutions.

Comment: Hi, I have big problems adapting the code to my real dataframe. I dont know whats the problem, but I get error massages all the time. It works so fine for my testframe. Could you please have a look on my real dataframes? I uploaded them and the link is above!

Comment: How are you reading those files into a data.frame?  Can you include code?
  I'm trying variations of `df1 <- readr::read_delim("https://megastore.uni-augsburg.de/get/IftpNjXNqL/", delim=" ")`.  It looks there are different problems with both.  In `df1`, the first column (of integers) doesn't have a row header.  In `df2`, I'm getting the error "invalid multibyte string 6" (using `readr::read_delim()` and `utils::read.delim()`) with the column like "H�he".

Comment: Oh, just download it! Its a .dat :/ I already have now a working solution. But thanks a lot for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

```
df1$NEW=df1[cbind(df2$Number,1:10)]
df1
     Station        Lon      Lat Number       Mis         NEW
1   Station1 -2.0000000 30.00000      1  4.000000 -0.50219235
2   Station2 -0.6666667 31.66667      3  5.333333 -0.58179068
3   Station3  0.6666667 33.33333      2  6.666667 -0.35986213
4   Station4  2.0000000 35.00000      1  8.000000 -0.20163395
5   Station5  3.3333333 36.66667      4  9.333333  2.31029682
6   Station6  4.6666667 38.33333      2 10.666667  0.76406062
7   Station7  6.0000000 40.00000      4 12.000000  0.23094453
8   Station8  7.3333333 41.66667      3 13.333333 -0.09111356
9   Station9  8.6666667 43.33333      3 14.666667 -0.69001432
10 Station10 10.0000000 45.00000      1 16.000000  0.18290768
```

Comment: That's pretty risky to assume for the entire dataset that the stations are always ordered the same way

Comment: That’s an easy fix. You use gsub.. will fix that right now

Comment: Sure is :) Just saying

Comment: After a thought I realized am drawing from every column sequentially..not bypassing any